# Graphical Decision Engine Framework - Any ideas?

Tags: software-rec, sql, query

Is there an open-source decision framework I could use?

What I am looking to create is some kind of graphical interface to allow people to visually build a query based on a set of parameters, ie. they can choose from a set of parameters, assign values and outcomes.. eg.

```
IF Raining OR Thunder then
IF DaysWithRain > 3
DISPLAY Umbrella
ELSE Raincoat
```

or

```
IF Day = Saturday OR Sunday
DISPLAY Deckchair
ELSE 
DISPLAY Desk
```

I would like people to be able to build this type of user-defined conditional logic arguments visually.

Any ideas on how I could do this easily using some existing codebase?

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood, but are you looking for something like Project Sikuli (http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for an example, iTunes has a decent set of boolean logic with it's Create Smart Playlist feature.

Most importantly, it is **limited** to a subset of boolean logic that most people can grasp without training.

In my experience, more advanced logic (e.g. using grouped and/or sets) is beyond what most users are willing to learn.

This doesn't mean that you shouldn't support more advanced logic, just that you should target the GUI aspect to your user's comfort level.